# Which sheet contains the duplicate?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, I have multiple sheets each with a column of numbers. I have it set up to highlight any cell that is a duplicate of a value on any sheet in the same column.

Also, how to have the sheet name(s) displayed in a cell to the left of the duplicate values?

For example; if I have sheetA, sheetB, and sheetC, each with a Number column, if I enter a value on sheetC that already exists on sheetA both cells will be highlighted. I would also like on sheetC the cell next to the duplicate value to change to "sheetA" indicating that the duplicate value is on sheetA.

I haven't been able to find any information that would even being to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use IF in combination with VLOOKUP or (ISNUMBER)MATCH the result of the IG is the text of the Sheet name, or if not found blank. I discurrage and showing the name and highlighting, but if you do, check for a nonblank value in the column of this formula

Comment: Show how you find the duplicates at the moment. Then that can be adapted, perhaps with cell().

Answer (score 0):

Formula for in which sheet number is found:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(COUNTIF(shee1!$A$1:$A$30;Sheet3!A1)>0;"Sheet1";"");IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$30;Sheet3!A1)>0;"Sheet2";""))
```

Formula for conditonal formatting (for sheet 3, do similar with other sheets):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1;VSTACK(shee1!$A$1:$A$30;Sheet2!$A$1:$A$30);0))
```

[image]